# Access user contacts in email input field (gmail)

Tags: email, input, google-apps-script, gmail

I've written a simple email form and I want to somehow connect this to the user's email so that email suggestions appear when typing into the input. This form will be used within a google sheets HTML add-on and so user will be logged into their gmail account at the time. Is there any way of incorporating this?

Comment: Are you saying that you are going to send the users suggestions via email as they type into the input text box?

Comment: no sorry, I just mean like an auto-complete function. Like you get in gmail whereby as you type, it brings up a list of your contacts dynamically

Comment: That sounds possible. Maybe try the onChange event of the text element for the email recipient. You could use a hidden div near recipient text and use the current letters in the text box to narrow the search result.